# SciPy sparse matrix indexed by logical sparse matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix

Let's consider sparse matrices

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.sparse as sps

A = sps.csc_matrix([[0, 1], [0, 0]])
L = sps.csc_matrix([[1, 1],[0, 0]]).astype(bool)
```

with `A` being an arbitrary numerical matrix and `L` being the sparse logical matrix used for consecutive reduction-by-choice.

The output of `print(A[L])`

```
matrix([[0, 1]])
```

then looks numerically OK, but the output type `numpy.matrix` is very unfortunate, as it is both *dense* matrix type and also a deprecated one.

**Is there any way to index a sparse matrix via another sparse matrix obtaining sparse matrix as a result?** I'm thinking about minimization of a computational overhead here.

Comment: Do'n't worry about the deprecation.  Let the developers change that if it ever becomes necessay.  `A[L].A1` should return a 1d array.  Remember normal boolean mask indexing returns a 1d result.

Comment: What 'computational overhead' do you have in mind?  I don't know how `sparse` implements this.  Row and column `sum` are done with a matrix multiplication, and also produce a dense `matrix`.  At some indexing is also done with matrix multiplication, using a 'extractor sparse matrix'.  Matrix multiplication is the most developed operation for these sparse matrices.  Indexing is not as well developed or efficient.  Boolean masking like this is, I suspect, rather rare.